# How do I send a literal parameter via Doctrine to the DB?

Tags: php, doctrine

If I want to do something like this (notice the expires line):

```
$duration=24; //in hours

$reset=new PasswordReset();
$reset->code=md5(uniqid());
$reset->expires="now() + interval $duration hours";
$reset->User=$user;
$reset->save();
```

How can I get Doctrine to NOT quote it before sending it to postgresql? I know I could do this in PHP, but I'd like to know for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Using Expression Values](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/component-overview:record:using-expression-values)

The given example looks like this *(quoting the doc)* :

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'jwage';
$user->updated_at = new Doctrine_Expression('NOW()');
$user->save();
```

And generates this SQL query :

```
INSERT INTO user (username, updated_at_) VALUES ('jwage', NOW())
```

I Suppose it would do, in your case ?

*(I don't have a Doctrine-enabled project right here, so can't test for you)*

*As a sidenote : I don't have a PostGreSQL server to test on ; but what you propose doesn't work on MySQL : it seems you have to use "`now() + interval 2 hour`", and not "`now() + interval 2 hours`" -- still, I don't know about PG*

---

**EDIT after the comment**

Ergh, you're right, this is not a correct solution ; it doesn't work **:-(**

Well... Interesting question, so I dug a bit more, and went to Doctrine's source-code ; I think I may have find something interesting.

If you look at the source of [`Doctrine_Query_Where::parseValue`](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/branches/1.1/lib/Doctrine/Query/Where.php#L139) source, you'll notice this portion of code :

```
// If custom sql for custom subquery
// You can specify SQL: followed by any valid sql expression
// FROM User u WHERE u.id = SQL:(select id from user where id = 1)
} elseif (substr($trimmed, 0, 4) == 'SQL:') {
    $rightExpr = '(' . substr($trimmed, 4) . ')';
// simple in expression found
```

I have absolutly not tried, but this might be interesting...

Maybe you could do something like this :

```
$reset->expires="SQL:(now() + interval $duration hours)";
```

If you try that, I'm very interested in knowing if it would work!

*Might be useful, one day or another ;-)*

BTW, it seems it's used in [`Doctrine_Search`](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/branches/1.1/lib/Doctrine/Search.php#L93) too ; looking at this one, maybe it'll work without the parentheses, like this :

```
$reset->expires="SQL:now() + interval $duration hours";
```

Well... I Hope, this time, it helps... Because I don't see much other way to do what you're trying to get *(and google doesn't help me either ^^ )*

---

**EDIT after the second (third, if counting mine) comment.**

*I will get this working... else I won't sleep well ^^*

Well, I might have found a way *(and, this time, I tested it ^^ )* ; not really as great as one would like, but, for updates anyway, it seems to be working...

Let's say I have a table created this way :

```
CREATE TABLE  `test1`.`test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `date_field` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The corresponding model class looks like this :

*Probably not perfect : it's a test-class I've written for something else, that I've mutated to fit this one ^^*

```
class Test extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('test');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'unsigned' => 0,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 32, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 32,
             'fixed' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('value', 'string', 128, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 128,
             'fixed' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('date_field', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'notnull' => true,
             ));
    }
}
```

I'll insert two lines into this table :

```
$test = new Test();
$test->name = 'Test 1';
$test->value = 'My Value 1';
$test->date_field = "2009-01-30 08:30:00";
$test->save();

$test = new Test();
$test->name = 'Test 2';
$test->value = 'My Value 2';
$test->date_field = "2009-02-05 08:30:00";
$test->save();
```

Which gets me this data from SQL :

*BTW : I don't have a pg server, so I'll test everything with MySQL -- should work on pg too, still...*

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+
| id | name   | value      | date_field          |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Test 1 | My Value 1 | 2009-01-30 08:30:00 |
|  2 | Test 2 | My Value 2 | 2009-02-05 08:30:00 |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, two lines, with dates long ago in the past.

Now, to be sure, let's just fetch the line #1 :

```
$testBefore = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->find(1);
var_dump($testBefore->toArray());
```

I'm getting this kind of output :

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Test 1' (length=6)
  'value' => string 'My Value 1' (length=10)
  'date_field' => string '2009-01-30 08:30:00' (length=19)
```

And, now, the interesting part : **let's update that line, using an expression like the one you provided** to set the `date_field` value :

```
$query = new Doctrine_Query();

$query->update('test')
    ->set('date_field', 'NOW() - interval 2 hour')
    ->where('id = ?', 1)
    ->execute();

var_dump($query->getSql());
```

The SQL that I get as output is this one :

```
string 'UPDATE test SET date_field = NOW() - interval 2 hour WHERE id = ?' (length=65)
```

Which kinda look like what you want, if I'm not mistaken ;-)

And, just to be sure, let's fetch our line once again :

```
$testAfter = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->find(1);
var_dump($testAfter->toArray());
```

And I get this result :

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Test 1' (length=6)
  'value' => string 'My Value 1' (length=10)
  'date_field' => string '2009-08-04 21:26:30' (length=19)
```

Considering the date and time, it seems this worked -- hoorray !

And, to be sure, let's query the data directly from the DB :

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+
| id | name   | value      | date_field          |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Test 1 | My Value 1 | 2009-08-04 21:26:30 |
|  2 | Test 2 | My Value 2 | 2009-02-05 08:30:00 |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And... Yeeeepe !

Well, now, the not so good parts : to be able to use that syntax, I had to create the query "by hand", to use the `set()` method, instead of doing it "nicely" with the model class and the `save()` method :-(

It's now up to you to see you that could be integrated into your model class... Have fun with that ;-)

And if you find a way, some day, to use expressions like this one in other parts of the query, or to do it a cleaner way, I'd really appreciate if you could post a comment to let me know **;-)**

*And, this, time, I sincerely hope I found the way ^^*

Comment: It looks like Doctrine_Expression is for using sql functions that Doctrine can convert into portable expressions. It doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Ergh :-( I've edited my answer with another idea... But, if this one doesn't work either, I'm afraid there is not much hope :-(

Comment: Thanks for digging, but it looks like Doctrine only looks for "SQL:" if its in a where clause. It doesn't seem to care if I do it when setting a value. +1 for the effort though, I appreciate it.

Comment: And one more edit... This time, I tested it (on MySQL), and it seems to be working... event if I don't like my solution that much (not using the model class enough... ). Hope this third try finally solves your problem !

Comment: Thanks so much! It's kind of strange that doctrine doesn't include easy support for something that I think would be needed fairly often. They must expect us to write raw sql if we want to use DB specific features. They should have you wrap something in Doctrine_Literal and have it used like Doctrine_Expression.

Comment: You're welcome :-) I think Doctrine doesn't include that by default is both before it doesn't seem to integrate that well in it's Doctrine_Record principle ; and because it is probably the "best" way to break compatibility between different DBMS : if you begin writting SQL by hand, instead of letting Doctrine generating it, you greatly increase the risk of it not being compatible with MySQL/PG/Oracle/...